# didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not push new view controller and also no error

Tags: iphone

I have a newb question.  I have a table view controller that's working fine at first glance.  It prints all the rows from my Nsmutabledictionary.  When I click on a row, it fires this function as expected without crashing or giving system errors:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    SCInventoryLeaf *childView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"inventoryleaf"];

    NSArray *keys = [arrInventory allKeys];
    id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    id anObject = [arrInventory objectForKey:aKey];
    childView.title = aKey;
    childView.price = [anObject objectForKey:@"price"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];
}
```

But for some reason, my childView is not presenting itself after the onRowClick.  I did properly name the identifier in my storyboard.

What could be wrong?  Where shoudl i troubleshoot next?

Edit -- I shold also mention that I put some breakpoints in viewDidLoad of SCInventoryLeaf.m, but they never seem to get fired.  So I'm guessing the SCInventoryLeaf.m is never used?   But I'm pretty sure I eastblished a relationship ebtween my tblviewcontroller and scinventoryleaf....

Comment: i'm sure this is some very newbish oversight, because i know i got this working before.

Comment: Very well posed question, good info - and good attempts at self-debugging before asking.

Comment: Side note: If you are using a storyboard, you can just connect the prototype cell to the SCInventoryLeaf with a modal segue and you'll get a presented view automatically. You can do your initial configuration in `prepareForSegue:`. You won't need an implementation of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at all.

Comment: Are you sure you ever execute the above method?  Add an NSLog of childView just ahead of the pushViewController, to make sure you get there and to make sure childView is not nil.  (You might also want to log self.navigationController, just for grins.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in a breakpoint and check to see that `childView` is not equal to `nil`. If it is, double-check that "inventoryleaf" is the correct case. Did you spell it "InventoryLeaf"? Cut and paste from your storyboard if needed.
The rest of your code looks fine.

Comment: "I shold also mention that I put some breakpoints in viewDidLoad of SCInventoryLeaf.m, but they never seem to get fired" That is really telling (and helpful), and I agree with @stevekohis. Try putting a break point and stepping thru `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, using the variables pane to see what's what. I'm betting that `childView` is nil because the identifier `inventoryLeaf` has a different capitalization in the storyboard than in your code, so they don't match.